# Transitively resolve download URLs of artifacts across multiple maven repositories

Tags: java, maven, aether

Given a list of repository URLs, a group, a name, and a version number, is there a simple way to resolve the download URLs for the artifact and all of its dependencies including transitive dependencies from an external application? I'm looking to use these URLs in an launcher applicatiom to download artifacts from the official sources, decreasing bandwidth on our less-than-ideal servers in the process.

I've tried using Shrinkwrap, however that just returns a list of artifacts, not what repository it fetched from. I've also tried using aether however it appears you cannot disable local resolution, which becomes an issue when building a remote URL.

Update: I've looked a bit more into aether today, and while I do think it's possible to get to work, it feels like a lot of effort for something that I feel should be relatively simple, considering gradle and maven do it.

Comment: Could you add some explanation about what your launcher application should do? Is it meant to be used for the build or for running the final application? How can it "decrease bandwidth"?

Comment: The launcher application pulls a JSON file down from my server which contains links to all of the artifacts that get put into a classloader together, so I can link to repositories such as maven central to download from there, instead of having to pull large shaded jars from my server.

Comment: And loading from the internet should be faster than loading from your own server? Usually, inside a company you have a Nexus or Artifactory that proxies all the external repositories and caches their artifacts. Downloading from this Nexus/Artifactory should then be super fast because it is in the same local network.

Comment: The application is used by end users as well as employees, 99.9% of time it's outside the local network, apologies for not making that clearer.

Comment: And your end users don't have Maven?

Comment: They do not, no

Comment: There's a maven wrapper that can download Maven w/o explicit installation, maybe that can be of help: https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper